# Capitalizing the first letter of every sentence python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, concatenation

I have been trying to create a small function for a menu project I have where the function takes a string as input and capitalizes the first letter of each sentence. I think I'm pretty close to having it right, but it keeps giving me a concatenation error that I can't seem to fix. Anyone know where I went wrong here?

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    s1 = usrStr.split(". ")
    s2 = [s1[0].capitalize() + s1[1:] for i in s1]
    st2 = '. '.join(s2)

    return st2
```

Comment: What is the concatenation error?

Comment: @Tom TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: Doesn't capitalize do what you want without having to use slices, anyway? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods - it only does the first letter in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the list comprehension you have s1[0] instead of i[0]

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    s1 = usrStr.split(". ")
    s2 = [i[0].capitalize() + i[1:] for i in s1]
    st2 = '. '.join(s2)

    return st2
```

Comment: and if I wanted to count how many letters were capitalized where would be the best place to add the code for that

Comment: should be a matter of how many sentences are in the string, so `len(s1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):

    return ".".join(list(map(lambda x: x.capitalize(),usrStr.split("."))))
```

This is more compact.
The 2nd argument in the map()--that is usrStr.plit()-- returns a list whose items are then worked on by the lambda function. The lamda function returns a list (created by the map function). The items in this list are joined by '.'